# Season (of a tv show)

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Kutime mi vidas ke oni uzas *sezono* por season. Ĉu sub la tria difino ĝi havas tiun sencon? "3 Jarparto, aparte taŭga aŭ favora por ia faro, okupo, komercofako ks. Aŭ ĉu estas pli taŭga vorto?

Answer (score 2):

> Sezono - Vico de filmoj laŭplane kaj regule publikigitaj kiel parto de serio http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sezon.html#sezon.0o

Comment: Tre interese. Mi pripensos. Tiu signifo ne trovigxas en PIV kaj mi ne povas trovi ekzemplon de la vorto uzata tiel. La citajxoj en ReVo estas de blogajxo kaj de artikolo en vikipedio - ambaux pri usonajxoj. Tio ne estas bona maniero eviti anglismojn. Mi demandis en la Lingva Konsultejo kaj redaktos mian respondon post kiam mi ricevos  kelkajn respondojn.

Answer (score 1):

Mi kontrolis la esprimon en kelkaj fremdaj lingvoj (inkluzive la britan), kaj mi tre dubas ĉu *sezono* havas tiun signifon en aliaj lingvoj. Cetere, la tria difino en PIV ne taŭgas. Ĝi estas por esprimoj kiel *la sezono de la ĉaso*.

Ŝajnas klare ke en Esperanto *televida serio* signifas ĉiujn epizodojn de unu programo. Por esprimi la ideon de *season* mi sugestas simple *jaro*, eventuale *epizodaro.*

- Post la dua jaro *Red Dwarf* jam ne uzis Esperanton en la epizodoj.
- Mi havas ĉiun epizodaron de Red Dwarf, krom la dekan.

Comment: Mi ne pensas ke tiuj suficxe bone esprimas kion oni celas. Pluraj "sezonoj" povas esti prezentataj dum la sama jaro. *Epizodaro* pli bonas, sed mi ne scias cxu mi gxuste komprenus tiun se iu dirus gxin al mi.

Comment: Cxu mankas unu j en la lasta ekzemplo?

Comment: Mia konkludo estas ke "sezono" en tiu senco estas anglismo. Se iuj kredus ke mi eraras, mi volonte legus respondon kiu klarigas kial "sezono" estas bona esprimo en Esperanto. Dankon pro la antentigo pri la malpara -J. Mi unue skribis ĉiujn epizodarojn kaj provis redakti al ĉiun epizodaron, sed ne finis.

Comment: Mi ne certas sed mi pensas ke iuj serioj havas du epizodarojn en unu jaro, do jaro eble estas klara sed iafoje ne. Epizodaro estas tre taŭga kaj klara. Dankon.

Comment: Mi tute konsentas ke "sezono" estas anglismo. Mi ne havas pli bonajn proponojn ol la viaj, do mi ecx kredas ke la anglismo povas esti la plej vaste komprenebla elekto.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Eble vi pravas, sed gxi estas en REVO http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sezon.html#sezon.0o

Comment: En la ĉeĥa, oni uzas la vorton vico (řada) por unu "sezono".  Ankaŭ "sezono" estas usonanismo, ne anglismo, angloj uzas "series" :)